# Exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I created one config server and try to accessing property file. Classpath for spring.cloud.config.native.search-locations is not working.

Scenario 1 :- when i use direct file path. it is working fine.

```
    spring:
      application:
        name: configserverdemo
      profiles:
        include: native
      cloud:
        config:
          server:
            defaultLabel: default
            native:
             search-locations: file:///C:/Users/config-prop/
```

Scenario 2 :- when i use classpath variable and try to access files from my application. It is not working.
Getting error 
      ***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location=***

```
     application.yml
        spring:
          application:
            name: configserverdemo
          profiles:
            include: native
          cloud:
            config:
              server:
                defaultLabel: default
                native:
                  search-locations: classpath:/config/${environment}, 
                                    classpath:/config/${environment}/{application}/
```

Code structure is something like

```
         src/main/resource -> config -> dev -> config-prop -> config-prop.properties


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>configserverdemo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>configserverdemo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description> 
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.example.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-common-starter-microservice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RELEASE</version>
        </parent>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <finalName>configserverdemo</finalName>
        </build>
    </project>



        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location=
            at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75) ~[spring-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.<init>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:89) ~[spring-core-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:42) ~[spring-boot-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:294) ~[spring-boot-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:128) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:45) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:53) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:107) [spring-cloud-config-server-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar:1.5.17.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]

        2020-01-17 16:24:24.300 DEBUG 17756 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public void org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.illegalArgument(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
        2020-01-17 16:24:24.302  WARN 17756 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location=]
        2020-01-17 16:24:24.302 DEBUG 17756 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
        2020-01-17 16:24:24.302 DEBUG 17756 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception and say what versions you are using?

Comment: The versions of spring cloud? Not the versions of your project. Maybe put the entries all on one line?

Comment: <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

Comment: Dalston is no longer supported. Please upgrade to boot 2.2.2 and Hoxton.SR1 and try again

Comment: I cannot upgrade spring boot version. it is 1.5 only. I tried with 1.5 and Hoxton.SR1. it is not working.

Comment: I tried to change search location like below. it was working. search-locations: classpath:/config/dev/config-prop . looks like ${environment} is not working.

Comment: boot 2.2.x is compatible with Hoxton. Boot 1.x is also EOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the variable ${environment} was not set in any of the application property files.

I created a variable called "environment" under **Run --> Run Configuration --> Environment** (key = environement, value = dev*).

When I set the value to different environments like "dev", "prod" or "stage" it is picking the respective file from config server.

***Now I need to create an external config file to provide the respective value for each environment.***